# What is meaning of y = x++ <= 2 in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have following code snippet in C Language.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    for( ; y ; printf("%d %d  ", x, y))
    {
        y = x++ <= 2;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It gives output like

```
2  1
3  1
4  0
```

I do not understand output and meaning of `y = x++ <= 2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`y = x++ <= 2` consists of 2 parts: (1) `x++` and (2) the assignment `y = ...`

`x++` simply means post incremental: you take the value of `x` and then you increment `x` by `1`.

assignment `y = ...` will set value of y as either 1 (if `x++ <= 2` is true) or 0 (if `x++ <= 2` is false)

Now the tricky part is your `for-loop`:

```
for( ; y ; printf("%d %d  ", x, y))
```

Note that in your `for-loop`, the `printf("%d %d  ", x, y)` (increment condition) will be printed *after* each loop.

and note the termination condition `;y;` which means that as long as your `y is 1` you will remain in the loop. Combining them all you get the result:

```
2 1 3 1 4 0
```

Sequentially it looks like this:

```
//first x = 1, y = 1
y = x++ <= 2; //x = 1 <= 2 returns 1, x++, x becomes 2, y becomes 1
printf("%d %d  ", x, y)// you get your first 2 1
y = x++ <= 2; //x = 2 <= 2 returns 1, x++, x becomes 3, y becomes 1
printf("%d %d  ", x, y)// you get your 3 1
y = x++ <= 2; //x = 3 <= 2 returns 0, x++, x becomes 4, y becomes 0
printf("%d %d  ", x, y)// you get your 4 0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
y = x++ <= 2;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (x <= 2)
  y = 1;
else
  y = 0;

x++;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 y = x++ <= 2;
```

This expression  checks if `x<=2` and assign the result to `y` and  increment `x` . As post increment operator `x` is incremented but its original value is used .

If `x<=2` then `y=1` else `y=0` , increment `x` and print `x` and `y` ,until `y` becomes `0`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers posted, please note that the code is some artificial "joke" code. You shouldn't write programs like that. Beyond a bit of academic operator precedence exercise, there's not much to learn from studying that code.

It has the following problems:

- Even though C allows all manner of weird things, the 3rd expression of a for loop should only be concerned with increasing the loop iterator. Therefore, only the `x++` should be there, not some printf statement.
- Always strive to write loops in their simplest, canonical form, which is `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`. This form is the most readable and usually also the form that yields fastest code.
- It is always best to start counting from `0` when dealing with computers.
- The variable `y` fills no purpose, it just adds confusion.
- The `++` operator should preferably not be mixed with other operators, since it contains a side effect (updating the variable). It is very easy to get all kinds of nasty bugs if you mix it with other operators. There is never a reason to do so anyway, you will not get any different machine code.

Here is an equivalent, clean version of the same algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  for(int x=0; x<3; x++)
  {
    printf("%d %d  ", x+2, x<2);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

(Double-checked by disassembling both snippets with gcc -O3 enabled, they yielded exactly the same machine code.)

Answer (score 2):

As this is not explained fully in any of the other answers, I will add it here. In C, there is a defined [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for how operators are handled. `y = x++ <= 2;` has 3 operators that are used: `=`, `++(post-increment)`, and `<=`.

The highest precedence operator with immediate evaluation is the `<=` operator. (Technically, the `++` operator has higher precedence, but its effect on x is not applied until after the assignment has taken place.) We can add parenthesis to show the order: `y = (x++ <= 2);`

The result of the comparison operators is either a `0` or `1` in C (because there is no `bool` or `boolean` type), which means that `y` will be assigned `0` or `1` depending on the outcome of the comparison.

The postfix increment operation doesn't happen until after the assignment of `y` is made. That means that `(x++ <= 2)` will behave like `(x <= 2)`, meaning that the value of `x` *before* it was incremented will be used the comparison.

If we broke this statement up, we could show how it would be evaluated.

```
y = x++ <= 2;
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
y = (x <= 2);
x++;
```

or, put more clearly (like weston has)

```
if(x <= 2)
    y = 1;
else
    y = 0;
x++;
```

The key to understanding this statement is operator precedence.